# How do I force a report to always insert a page break?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, report, rdlc

I created a report in Visual Studio 2012 that has two report definitions. The main report section repeats once per vehicle, and it has a subreport that repeats once for each delivery that vehicle has.

The main report design looks as follows:

[image]

The orange bar on the left side indicates that the rectangle on which I have all the other elements located is selected.

I have set the following properties on it:

[image]

I have also set `Add a page break before` and `Add a page break after` on the Tablix that contains the other elements:

[image]

There is no other Rectangle or Tablix on this report design.

My problem is that it doesn't always do a page-break before and after. On pages with only a little information, it puts each vehicle on the same page, as follows:

[image]

But when a vehicle is longer than a single page, it spills into the next page, and the next vehicle *does not add a page break before it*, like so:

[image]

How can I force the report to always insert a page break before a new vehicle?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Maybe these links could help you.

Goodluck!

- [How to add a page break (Report Designer)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa179452%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)
- [How to: Set Page Breaks (Visual Studio Report Designer)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251733%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
- [Defining Page Size and Page Breaks in a Report (Visual Studio Report Designer)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251701%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

**Update by original poster**

Reading all the instructions on the previous pages, I found the a solution. My main report tablix needed to be grouped into individual rows, and those row groups needed page breaks.

*To add a page break to a grouping in a table*

- In Layout view, click the table so that column and row handles appear above and next to the table.
- Right-click the row handle on the right side of your row group Tablix, go into the `Row Group` submenu, and then click `Group Properties...`.
- The Tablix needs to be grouped by the rows you want page breaks between. On the `General` tab, add a `Group on` expression. In my case, it was VehicleID.
- On the Page `Breaks` tab, click `Between each instance of the group`
- Click `OK`

Comment: I am using 2010 VSRD. Is it possible to access and set the pagebreaks (by groups, by row number) programmatically and count total number of pages per report?